# Laravel not connecting to homestead database

Tags: laravel, homestead

I was developing a laravel application locally on Mac connecting to a mysql database. i recently found out about homestead and pulled my app over to Vagrant Homestead. however now im not able to connect to the mysql server on the homestead/box.

Error i recieve:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I did update my app's .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=eHDatabase
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I cleared my app's cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

I updated `my /etc/hosts` file

```
27.0.0.1        localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel.app
```

and i also removed the old mysql server running on port 3306 on 127.0.0.1.
but still recieve the connection error.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please show you `/config/database.php`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin http://laravel.io/bin/GyOEm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `.env` and `/config/database.php` are looking fine, so try to run this:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. will tick it as soon as it comes available. however now it cant find any of my blade files.